# popup window only 'popping up' once in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a JavaScript fired popup window, it's created when hitting the onclick event of a  tag:

```
top.popUp('/bus/popup.asp', '', 'height=457px,width=525px,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no');return false;">

function popUp(url, winName, params, win)
{
    var winExists = false;

    if (win.handler)
    {
        if (!(win.handler == "" || win.handler.closed || win.handler.name == undefined))
        {
            winExists = true;
        }
    }   

    if (!winExists)
    {
        win.handler = window.open(url, winName, params)
    } 
    try
    {
        win.handler.focus();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    }
    return false;
}
```

I also found these two funky little functions in the main file, fired when the popup window gets unloaded:

```
// Hack for onUnload and onBeforeUnload
onBeforeUnloadHappened = false;
closeDirectly = false;

function onBeforeUnloadHandler()
{
if (!closeDirectly)
{
    openerUnhilightSaveLink();
    onBeforeUnloadHappened = true;
}
}
function onUnloadHandler()
    {
if (!closeDirectly)
{
    if (!onBeforeUnloadHappened)
    {
        openerUnhilightSaveLink();
    }   
    else
    {
        onBeforeUnloadHappened = false;
    }
}   
}
```

The problem is that in Safari, the window will only popup once, each subsequent click on the link gets you nada, zilch, nothing... how do I correct this?

I did find a couple of articles, Google is my friend, online and they suggested that I add this.close(), which I did to the unload event but it doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

The other thing I find odd is that the onUnloadHandler() doesn't actually happen each time the page is unloaded!  Shouldn't this be called each time by the page itself irrespective of what else has happened?!

Thanks

Comment: without seeing the code for the function popUp it's real hard to give you any advice since top.popUp is not  native javascript function.

Comment: There is the 4th parameter missing in the call, "win" will be undefined.

Comment: It's not defined, so open one!

Comment: No, you will get an error(in every browser, not only Safari) on  **`if(win.handler)`** when win is undefined. You must first check if win is defined to avoid this error. **`if(win && win.handler)`**

Comment: I tried adding your line 'if(win && win.handler)' but to no avail - I also checked with a JavaScript debugger and no error!

Comment: Your debugger is not working well. I guess everybody here will receive errors when testing your code. win never gets initialized somwhere inside your code, so every attemt to access or set a property of win will end up in an error, e.g. this: **`win.handler = window.open(url, winName, params)`**

Answer (score 0):

It's my opinion that your popup code isn't written properly.  This works in Safari, as I just tested it out.  This is what I've done.

```
// Create a global popup object as you should rarely ever
// have more than one popup open at a time.
window.popUpObj = null;

// The function to call the popup.
function popUp(url, winName, params)
{

  // If the window has not been defined or if it has been closes open it.
  // Since we defined window.popUpObj to be null we'll expect only 2 conditions.
  if(window.popUpObj == null || window.popUpObj.closed)
  {
    window.popUpObj = window.open(url, winName, params);
  }

  // Get window focus
  window.popUpObj.focus();

  // Return false.
  // we do this so that when we call it we don't need a ; to return false afterwards
  // we just add return before the function call.  It's a bit more elegant.
  return false;
}
```

You can call it like this.  You should by the way always populate the 2nd parameter with something.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return popUp('/bus/popup.asp', '_blank', 'height=457px,width=525px,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no');">Link</a>
```

Here's a working HTML doc.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   window.popUpObj = null;

    function popUp(url, winName, params)
    {
      // If the window has not been defined or if it has been closes open it.
      if(window.popUpObj == null || window.popUpObj.closed || window.popUpObj.name == undefined)
      {
        window.popUpObj = window.open(url, winName, params);
      }

      // Get window focus
      window.popUpObj.focus();

      // Return false.
      return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <a href="#" onclick="return popUp('http://www.google.com/', '_blank', 'height=457px,width=525px,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,location=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no');">Link</a>

    <a href="#" onclick="window.popUpObj.close(); return false;">close</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't write this, I have however been tasked with fixing it!

Comment: lol, no problem.  I haven't worked with popups in years, so it was a stroll down memory lane.  Please remember to accept it if the code works out for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't 'work for me!'  I think the issue is with the way the window in being closed, not with the opener sequence; I will dig around for the close code.  Thanks though.

Comment: How is the window being closed?

Comment: The other thing I find odd is that the onUnloadHandler() doesn't actually happen each time the page is unloaded!  Shouldn't this be called each time by the page itself irrespective of what else has happened?!

Comment: Yes, but only if the pages is fully loaded.  You my friend have inherited what I like to call as a nightmare.  You have so much going on that it's not just a simple open close problem you probably have a breaking javascript problem.  You should be using the Safari console if you aren't and see if it triggers an error on close.